# Why and how will the string break?

Tags: classical-mechanics, electricity, molecules

While i was searching on the identity discussed earlier that is

$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + ... = -\frac{1}{12}$$

I found a similar identity applied to physics concept. It started by arranging long molecule modeled as a 1-dimensional string with alternating charges +q ,-q ,+q,-q and so one spaced evenly.

The force between adjacent charges is known, it states that by pulling on one end of the molecule which is slowly increasing with time. One could determine the maximum force you can pull on the string so that the string  does not break.
and that it could be determined by using the identity

$\sum _{ n=1 }^{ \infty  }{ { (-1) }^{ n-1 } } \frac { 1 }{ { n }^{ 2 } } =\frac { { \pi  }^{ 2 } }{ 12 }$

I really don't know how pulling on one end of a  string will cause it to break somewhere along the string. Any ideas
Thanks

Comment: Which question are you stuck on? A string fixed at one end will break when enough tension is applied. Sounds like somewhere in the equation of molecular tensile forces within the string that particular infinite sum shows up.  Is that what you want?

Comment: The thing is the other end isn't attached to anything, all you do is apply a force at one end increasing it with time.

Comment: You cannot pull on the end of an infinite series of strings. There is no end all the points are in the middle.

Comment: Well it doesn't have to be infinite -- just that the infinite sum is an upper bound on the finite sum.  Think of a long train of boxcars & calculate how long it has to be for the first coupling to break.

Comment: How have u progressed on this problem?

Comment: By applying the force you cause the string to accelerate and there is a tension in the string as each unit has to pull all those behind it. I doubt you will get a break in the first "joint" because there is a boundary condition and the electrostatic forces are strongest there and at the other end. But somewhere near the front, the mass of the string being pulled along will be too much for the strength of the bond. Pi squared over 12 is about 0.8 and I have no idea what that is applied to.